# Concatenar valores de um Banco em SQL

Tags: sql

Usando SQL eu estou fazendo um registro que irei dar um SELECT em um banco no qual alguns registros vem duplicados que é estruturado da seguinte forma com a mesma adesão ex:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|     ADE    | COLUMN_NAME | IS_IDENTITY |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|    caio    |      3      |      10     |
|    caio    |      4      |       4     |
|    caio    |      4      |       8     |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

e quero agrupar os dados da seguinte forma numa mesma célula, no qual a divergência estará concatenada com o IdMotivo separada por " - " e os motivos da divergência por "," e para separação das agrupação das divergências por "|" ficando da seguinte forma ex:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|     ADE    |   DIVERGÊNCIA - MOTIVO    |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|    caio    |       3-10 | 4-4, 8       |     
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

ja tentei usar GROUP e PIVOT junto, mais não sei usar mto bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em postgresql fica fácil de fazer usando o with.

Dada a tabela:

```
﻿|nome           |divergencia    |motivo         |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|caio           |3              |10             |
|caio           |4              |4              |
|caio           |4              |8              |
|maria          |3              |5              |
|maria          |3              |10             |
```

Essa consulta:

```
with tb_motivos as (
    select nome, divergencia, string_agg(motivo, ',') as motivo
    from ade
    group by nome, divergencia
    order by motivo
) 
select nome, string_agg(divergencia || ' - ' || motivo, '|') as div_mot 
from tb_motivos
group by nome
order by nome, div_mot
```

Trará o resultado:

```
|nome   |div_mot      |
|-------|-------------|
|caio   |3-10|4-4,8   |
|maria  |3-5,10       |
```